# Soft-shell spinner suitcase with brakes (and external side pockets)? Does it exist?

Tags: luggage, gear

I have found several hard-shell spinner (i.e., 4 wheeled) suitcases with brakes (e.g. from European manufacturers Delsey and Stratic), but have yet to come across any with soft-shells (that also have pockets on the outside for small items). Does anyone know of such a product, or perhaps could offer a reason why there is none (even for hard-shelled luggage there aren't so many to choose from)? Or alternatively, one with retractable wheels (where you can still use two wheels like you would a with a 2-wheel suitcase)? Another possibility would be a braking mechanism that can be purchased separately and used (fairly easily) on spinner luggage.

Here are some examples of hard-shelled spinners with brakes:

- https://eminent.com/products/4-wheel-trolley-42/
- https://aliexpress.com/item/Luggage-female-universal-wheels-trolley-luggage-travel-bag-male-hard-case-luggage-20-inch-brake-universal/32739989295.html
- http://www.muji.us/store/valise-hard-carry-travel-suitcase-33l-sky-blue4549738185062.html

The brakes on the suitcases I listed (usually) just lock the two rear wheels, enabling the suitcase to still be pulled behind on the two front wheels, while preventing the suitcase rolling away when on an incline or on a accelerating/de-accelerating train.

Update:

- I prefer soft-shell suitcases because they usually have outer pockets, which is useful for quick, last-minute storage and retrieval of smaller items. I also like the fact that they can expand slightly if you pack something bulky inside. Plus they don't break like some hard-shell cases do (of course they can tear, but that is usually different circumstances).
- The advantage of a 4-wheel vs 2-wheel suitcase for me: The spinner can be pushed down a crowded aisle of a train rather than pulling it behind me (since it can be pushed in all directions it will fit down a narrow aisle better than the 2-wheeler).

Update 2:

I found that Muji once sold a soft-shell spinner with wheel lock, but it seems to no longer be for sale:

http://pinterest.com/pin/253679391482807196/

Comment: My thought is that hard shells are used because it allows the suitcase to "stand up". If it were soft shell, it would just slouch. There are only so many ways to customize a suitcase with 4 wheels. There are soft shell ones with 2 wheels and a hard back where the retractable handle is attached.

Comment: @MichaelC.: But there are soft shell suitcases with four wheels.

Comment: Why does a suitcase need brakes in he first place?

Comment: @JonathanReez Actually, I have though about this on angled JetBridges when trying to manage the spinner, personal item, phone call and etc...  I end up lodging it against my foot.

Comment: _"The spinner can be pushed down a crowded aisle of a train rather than pulling it behind me"_ - I do this all the time with my two wheeler, except I push it in front rather than pulling it behind me.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: But then you have to push the wider side of the suitcase rather than the narrower one. With a 4-wheeler you can push it on either side.

Comment: Requests for product recommendations have many of the same [problems shopping questions do](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), among them the matter of availability as time and the market progress, and the fact that by the time sufficient detail has been added to make the question answerable, it is too narrow to be of much help to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You referenced Delsey, and it does have a soft-side version, with a exterior slip-case, not zippered pouches. 
Made of:

> - Lightweight and durable; constructed of 380d polyester with Teflon protection and stylish faux leather trim
> - Smart Innovation; A Stop and Go brake system is activated with a button and locks the two front wheels of the luggage, preventing the bag from drifting away while allowing travelers to roll the bag on the two back wheels

The series is called Chatelet, in three sizes: 21, 27, and and 30 inches.

[Amazon US](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EL5U7C0) has it, as does [eBags (from which this description and image was borrowed)](http://www.ebags.com/search?term=delsey%20chatelet%20soft&pl=hdr_srch_sf_l1).

It is also on [Amazon.de, as Delsey Koffer](https://www.amazon.de/Delsey-Koffer-schokoladenbraun-braun-00177182006/dp/B01ABL6E3Y/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1492009804&sr=8-9&keywords=delsey%20chatelet).

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for finding this, I was aware of the hard-cover Chatelet series from Delsey, but not this soft-side version. Too bad it doesn't have zippered pouches on the outside. I will wait a while and see if anyone knows of ones with zippered pouches before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: @newenglander sure thing; I find that [Samsonite](https://www.google.com/patents/US5147019) had the original patent; still looking for other options.

Comment: The only thing I have found so far is this suitcase, which looks promising but it's bulk order only: http://www.globalmarket.com/product-info/expandable-travel-set-bag-trolley-suitcase-luggage-spinner-with-brake-11323250.html

Comment: @newenglander proceed cautiously... and google whether the site is legit, check any consumer complaints.

Comment: Don't worry, I won't be ordering 500 suitcases (that's the minimum order!).

Answer (score 1):

Stratic has released a new line of soft-shelled suitcases with brakes and external side pockets (but the brakes stop all wheels from moving rather than just the front two, meaning it can't be pulled when the brakes are on, a feature other models have): [image]https://www.stratic.de/en/reisegepack/weichgepack/go-first-stop-later